# Sonarqube is not checking css and js inside html

Tags: javascript, css, sonarqube

I´m trying to find a way so Sonarqube can check bugs/issues/errors on css and js inside html code.
I created a simple html snippet, and then I add js inside  tag and css inside  tag, but Sonarqube is not making any check.
For js, I add common code issues that I found here https://www.sonarsource.com/js/, but with no luck.

Does anyone knows how to force Sonarqube to check css or js inside html?

Thanks

Comment: Here refer this https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.9/analysis/languages/javascript/

Comment: @SouravAtta regarding the documentation that you mentioned, do you suggest to implement a custom rule?

Comment: Hello, I would recommended to move styles to the `*.css` files.